# How to display object values using for/in loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have written a for/in loop which displays the properties for the object person here:

```js
const composer = {
  name: 'Edward Ellington',
  nickname: 'Duke',
  genres: ['jazz', 'swing'],
  instrument: 'piano'
};

for (let prop in composer) {
  console.log(`${prop}: ${composer[prop]}`);
}
```

My question is how do I now display the values of the object?  I apologize if this has already been answered but I did not find this question in my search.

I have tried to add this below console.log:
console.log(composer.values(object1));
But it tells me this is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: Can't see your code, can update your question with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `Object.values`.

```js
const composer = {
  name: 'Edward Ellington',
  nickname: 'Duke',
  genres: ['jazz', 'swing'],
  instrument: 'piano'
};
const values = Object.values(composer);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: @AmyHendrix No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your code. I think what you are asking is can be achieved as follows:

```js
for (let key in obj) {
  // value is accessed with this notation `obj[key]`
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```